# How to remove rows in a dataframe by a specific id number?

Tags: r, database, data-cleaning, medical

I have a dataframe (et5) with many columns and observations. One of the columns is "MRN" which is a code unique to each observation/patient in the dataframe, another is "Age". First, how can I display all of the MRNS and ages side by side? Second, how can I then remove certain observations/patients specifically by MRN.

What my dataframe (et5) looks like

```
    mrn    Patient's Aneurysm   Age
    12345   Aortic              34
    12344   Iliac               94
    29339   Aortic              49
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr, select mrn and Age:

```
et5 %>%
select(mrn, Age)
```

Remove cases:

```
et5 %>%
filter(!mrn == 12345)
```

Comment: how would I select multiple MRNs to delete

Comment: also is there a way to sort by descending age (largest to smallest)?

Comment: i. filter(!mrn == c(12345, 13333, 15365))

Comment: ii. et5[sort(et5$Age, decreasing = T), ]